# How do I run R shiny app from RHEL linux server on LAN?

Tags: r, shiny, rhel

I am trying to share R Shiny apps with co-workers off a Linux server.

I have already successfully shared an app with my co-workers off my desktop by using my ip address, but I wanted to move it to a server so it could run all the time.  My work provided me with a RHEL Linux server and I moved the same R script onto the server.  The only thing I changed was the ip address for the server (found with the command "hostname -i").

The script seems to run without errors on the server, but when I try to access the app through a browser on my desktop using it won't connect.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a little more a "linux" question than an "R" question. Are you using `shiny-server` or something "proper" for running the shiny instance for multiple users, or are you running it in an instance of R (with or without RStudio) on linux? You can often find the port being used using `netstat -apnt` (not in R) and looking for your expected port to see if the "Local Address" is localhost only, `0.0.0.0` (indicating all interfaces), or a specific IP address/interface.

Comment: Right now I'm just running an instance of R. I'm in the process of having shiny-server installed but it is taking a while to navigate IT. When I do "netstat -apnt" I get about a dozen lines of output. Some with local address "0.0.0.0" but also some with the address I get from "hostname -i". It seems the only ones with a state of "ESTABLISHED" are with the hostname. Only one of these has anything in "Send-Q". Is that the address that I should be using?

Comment: The `netstat -pant` should include the process name at the end. If you see R or any R-based process (shiny-server, perhaps), then that is the appropriate line. Probably helpful is that you should (1) `| grep LISTEN`, and (2) some process names are unavailable to normal users, so you might need to fish around a bit. Do you have `sudo` access?

Comment: It's seems to be running on a local address "127.0.0.1:1234".  THe "PID/Program name" for that says 19399/R.  I don't have sudo access.

Comment: I think that's your answer: it is running on localhost only, so nobody else can see it. Have you looked into how to get a local R instance to share on a different IP? ([`?runApp`](https://rdrr.io/cran/shiny/man/runApp.html) lists `host=` or `options(shiny.host=...)`.)

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks so much.